# Program acting differently depending on user

Tags: shell, sudo, php, raspberry-pi

I am trying to control an RC transmitter from a PHP site. The command works fine as user "xbian" in the command line:

```
sudo /home/xbian/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend 34832404
```

for example, and it works fine.

So I am using this code on the php page:

```
shell_exec("sudo /home/xbian/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend {$num} >/tmp/debug.log 2>&1");
```

And this line in sudoers:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/xbian/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend
```

And as expect I get an output file:

> sending code[34832404]

Which I don't get without the sudoers line. So the command is running as sudo as it should but for some reason, after all this, it simply doesn't work like it does when I just run the shell command normally.

The actual thing that requires sudo is [the "WiringPi" library](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/download-and-install/) which is called in the C++ program "codesend". I assume something is going wrong there but I have no clue how to troubleshoot it. No errors occur in the codesend program and nothing else it output from the command. I'm running PHP 5.4.4 and using Prefork mpm. This page is only accessible on my local network so I am not too worried about security at this point, just getting it to work.

How can I figure out where the problem is?

Comment: Does it work if you're logged in as `www-data`? Try `su www-data` then run your command: `sudo /home/xbian/433Utils/RPi_utils/codesend 34832404`

Comment: @terdon Yes, it works when I do that.

Comment: Check your environment. If that is a shell script, it's possible some utility it's trying to call isn't in `$PATH`. To debug, have it dump out `env` to a file, and compare the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use pilight (http://www.pilight.org) when you want to do home automation with your Raspberry Pi. That program is especially made for that purpose.

To be more clear after the comment below. I run pilight and XBMC on the same Raspberry Pi for more than a year without issues. That way i can control my lights even with my TV remote controller. So no need to buy additional Raspberry Pi's.

Comment: I have a Raspberry Pi always running for my XBMC server. The goal was to add this on so that I don't need extra hardware like an additional arduino or raspberry pi.